# Addiing captions above images in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image

So I added some code in my css and there are boxes that appear over every image that is attached to a post. I've wanted to number the images and show the image number in the box(1...n). I have this in my functions.php

edit: code was added here http://pastebin.com/gVszwf75

If I run only count_images it will show the correct number of attached images to a post(let's say 15). But for some reason the number that is shown in the boxes over the images is always 1. I've seen this done on several blogs with just php so there has to be a way(even if I have to change my whole code).

Comment: Please format your code by indenting them with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're looping through the array each time you call your callback function `caption_image_callback()` ... it has no memory of how many times it's looped!

The easiest way to fix this is to add a global variable at the beginning of the plug-in, I call it `$caption_image_count` and set it equal to zero.  Then call the variable in `caption_image_callback()` and increment by 1 each time you call the function.  This will keep track of the number of captioned images you have on the page.

If you want, you can also re-set the variable to zero before you return `$post_body_content` in `caption_image()`.  I've posted the full solution to your pastebin: http://pastebin.com/sFe6dhqL